# Disable wpf resource inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation

For performance and isolation reasons, I have an application that uses cross-process communication, and utilizes  `System.AddIn.Pipeline.FrameworkElementAdapters.ContractToViewAdapter()` and `System.AddIn.Pipeline.FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter()` methods to transfer the GUI controls from the plugin processes to the host process.

The plugin GUI controls are mostly Microsoft-provided controls supporting a rehosted Microsoft Workflow Foundation interface.  Many of these have hard-coded colors and brushes in their xaml definitions, and are not easily rethemed.

I support two different host applications.  One of them has extensive theming via an Application-level ResourceDictionary, and the other does not do any custom theming.

In the application with no custom theming, controls display thusly
[image: Toolbox in unthemed host application]

But in the application with custom theming, it looks like this
[image: Toolbox in themed host application]

It picks up some of the theme from the host application, but because the Microsoft controls hard-code much of their colors, it's incomplete and looks awful.

I've used Snoop to find the brushes and colors that the themed application is forcing onto these controls, and from that, I made a resource dictionary with the right colors.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" 
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Color x:Key="aC03">#FF000000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC09">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC10">#FF858C9D</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC11">#FF000000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC13">#FF8C9097</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC14">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC15">#FF777D87</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC16">#FF6E7582</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC17">#FFE9ECEE</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC20">#FF000000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="aC21">#FF000000</Color>

    <GradientStopCollection x:Key="aG01">
        <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="{StaticResource aC10}" />
        <GradientStop Offset="0.10" Color="{StaticResource aC13}" />
        <GradientStop Offset="0.49" Color="{StaticResource aC15}" />
        <GradientStop Offset="0.50" Color="{StaticResource aC16}" />
        <GradientStop Offset="1.00" Color="{StaticResource aC16}" />
    </GradientStopCollection>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlTextBrush" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC03}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlBrush" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC14}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox_Default_Layer1" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC14}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox_Default_Layer2" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC21}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox_Default_Layer3" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC11}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox_Default_Layer2" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC20}" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox_Default_Layer3" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" GradientStops="{StaticResource aG01}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox_Default_Text" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC03}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBrush" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC17}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContextMenu_Layer1" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" Color="{StaticResource aC09}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I apply this resource dictionary to either the root rehosted control, or that and all of its children, it looks like this

[image]

So even overriding the resources seems to be insufficient.

Is there a way to suppress/prevent/disable resource inheritance, or do I need to override each and every resource (color, brush, style, template, et.c) that affects my controls?

**Edit:** The style overriding code was requested.  I've tested running the following on the Loaded event and the Initialized event (individually, not together), and running on the GUI thread vs in a task.  Calling it on the loaded event produces some change, calling it on the initialized event does not

```
    var resources = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WorkflowRemoting;component/Host/ResourceOverride.xaml") };

    Action<DependencyObject, ResourceDictionary> 
        SetResources = null;
    SetResources = (element, dictionary) =>
    {
        DependencyObject[]
            children = null;
#if runInTask
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
#endif
            var nChildren = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
            children = Enumerable.Range(0, nChildren).Select(x => VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, x)).ToArray();
#if runInTask
        });
#endif
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
#if runInTask
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
#endif
                var fe = child as FrameworkElement;
                if (fe != null)

                    if (this.Resources == null)
                        fe.Resources = dictionary;
                    else
                        fe.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
#if runInTask
            });
#endif
            SetResources(child, dictionary);
        }
    };

#if runInTask
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
#endif
        SetResources(this, resources);
#if runInTask
    });
#endif
```

Comment: I've edited the question to show that section of code, how I've tried executing it, and the results

Comment: why don't you use xaml for overriding resources?

Comment: I was under the impression that setting the resource dictionary is effectively the same thing.  In any case, that's only an option for controls for which I can edit the xaml.  Most of the controls are part of System.Activities.Presentation, and Microsoft did not design them with customization in mind

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the controls, just zero out the style for each of the controls as such:

```
<Button Style="{x:Null}" Content="Press me"/>
```